# Way to getNext() within the same category

Tags: relations, structure

I'm trying to get the next and previous entries in a structure but I only want the next or previous ones within the same category?

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
{% set next = entry.getNext().relatedTo(category).first() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close! `getNext` and `getPrev` take an ElementCriteriaModel as a parameter:

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category) %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```

Or, if you prefer, a params array (same as you would pass to `craft.entries` ElementCriteriaModel):

```
{% set params = {
    section: 'news',
    relatedTo: category,
} %}
```